# How to add 'add to cart' button to view based on a search index?

Tags: commerce, search

Just got started with search_db and the search_api and facets. I have a view set on an index of my commerce products, but I don't have the option to add the 'add to cart' form as a field. There isn't an option to pull one in from a related field that I can see either. Any help would be appreciated.

thnx

Comment: Is the index on the nodes that are related to the commerce products, or on the commerce products themselves? Have you tried to add a relationship?

Comment: The index is on  the commerce_products, not the nodes. The only options for related fields are "creator, price, image, and two options for users". I'm not sure if this is something the commerce_cart_extras or the commerce_search_api takes care of? the documentation is a little circular.

Comment: Why don't you try to add an index on the nodes that are related to the commerce products? There should be a views field plugin for an add to cart form for them.

Comment: So I looked into setting the index on my product display nodes. Without deleting the previous index, I created another one on just the nodes. I had to add a relationship on the product sku to get access to the fields I was interested in. The only problem is that the view doesn't display anything. So...not sure where to go from here. There's plenty of references to this being a problem and/or solved in DC, but I still have this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the index from the Commerce Products to the product displays, and this got me a different range of field choices. I could have probably achieved a similar result by adding a relationship, but I wanted this to be relatively clean and simple.